# Add a Filtered View to the Site Map

Tags: dynamics-crm-2013

In CRM 2011 and before, it was quite easy to put a filtered view onto the sitemap as the views were URL addressable.  I've tried to do similar in 2013 but am not having any luck.  In the SubArea URL I've put

```
main.aspx?etn=contact&pagetype=entitylist&viewid={DE953224-94B9-E311-93F0-005056A03E30}
```

but the UI just seems to get in a confused state. pagemode=iframe doesn't make any difference.

Any ideas?  Anyone achieved this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sitemap has a particular way of setting addressable views.  Unfortunately your approach is supported for everything but the sitemap (source link at bottom).

> **Display a View in the Application Navigation using the Site Map**
>
> When you customize the application navigation using the site map, do
>   not use the view URL that you copied from the application using the
>   steps in Copy the URL for a View to set as the URL. That URL displays
>   a page that includes the ribbon and produces undesirable results if
>   used in a `<SubArea> (SiteMap)` Url attribute.
>
> To display a list of
>   entity records within the application for a SubArea set the Entity
>   attribute value. This displays the default view for that entity and
>   provides the correct title and icon.
>
> However, if you want to have a
>   SubArea element that uses a specific initial default view, use the
>   following Url pattern.

**XML:**

`Url=“/_root/homepage.aspx?etn=<entity logical name >&amp;viewid=%7b<GUID value of view id>%7d”`

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg328483.aspx

Comment: That did it.  Thanks.  Missed that page in the sdk.  Good catch.

Answer (score 1):

My main advice would be to use a Site Map editor. There's a few out there. [XrmToolbox](http://xrmtoolbox.codeplex.com/) on Codeplex for starters. Or the app from [Simpler Software](http://www.crmsolutionmanager.com/Download.aspx).  That'll take care of your XML for you. I haven't tried hand cranking the Site Map for a very long time. Haven't had to.

Answer (score 0):

For people that the answer did not work:

/main.aspx?pagetype=entitylist&etn=ENTITYNAME&viewid={GUID}

Source: https://community.dynamics.com/forums/thread/details/?threadid=e8d0783c-0dee-42a6-9e12-16236e4ec073

Comment: Please explain the effect of what you propose and explain why it solves the problem.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35387124)